# IEnumerable.ElementAt - Argument Out Of Range Exception when Value Exists

Tags: c#, exception, ienumerable

I have this piece of code that gets a random number from the count of a list (-1) and then gets the element at that index. I then remove the object from that list and the code is called until all objects are gone from that list.

I'm a bit confused as to how there can be 13 indexes (0-12) and the integer I'm using to get the element at is 11. How can this be out of range of the valid values?

```cs
private Player GetRandomPlayer(List<Player> entries)
{
            var rIdx = rnd.Next(entries.Count - 1);
            var player = entries.Where(i => i.Seed == null).ElementAt(rIdx);
            entries.Remove(player);

            return player;            
}
```

Images of exceptions and test case:

List with 13 values:
https://ibb.co/wQdq1q4

Exception including int used to get a value:https://ibb.co/mJXwMFh

Comment: Your rIdx is valid only on the _entries_ list, not for a sublist containing only Seed==null (unless all elements of entries have null in that property)

Comment: `Where(i => i.Seed == null)` apply *filter* on `entries` and so `entries.Where(i => i.Seed == null).Count()` can well be *less then* `13` and `ElementAt(rIdx)` will throw Argument Out Of Range Exception

Comment: minor note, but there is no need for the `ref` here...

Comment: Better to sort the existing players randomly and then remove the first or last player from random  list :             Random rand = new Random();
            List<Player> sortedList = entries.Select(x => new { player = x, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.player).ToList();

Comment: @MarcGravell I thought it was required because I'm using the entries list outside of the method. Rather than returning an amended entries list each time and setting this each time the method is called, I figured it'd be cleaner to use the ref keyword?

Comment: @JordanGW that's not how references work; a `List<T>` is an **object**, so even if you have just `List<Player> entries` (no `ref`), the calling code is passing the *reference* to the list; the list itself doesn't get cloned when you pass it - it is just a *copy* of the *reference* to the list. The only thing `ref` would allow here is : for `GetRandomPlayer` to change `entries` to point to a *completely different list object*, and for the calling code to see that reassignment. Changes to the existing object will *always* be observed by both caller and callee, with or without the `ref`

Comment: @MarcGravell ah ok, a misunderstanding on my part.Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ElementAt()` method works on the return value of your `Where` clause. If there are less than `rIdx+1` elements having `Seed == null` you get the exception.

By *assuming* what you want to achieve, I think this should work:

```
// filter list
var nullEntries = entries.Where(i => i.Seed == null).ToList();

// use only filtered values
var rIdx = rnd.Next(nullEntries.Count - 1);
var player = nullEntries[rIdx];
entries.Remove(player);
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The choice of `rIdx` counts *everyone*; but not *everyone* will match the predicate `i => i.Seed == null`. So if there are 13 players, 3 unseeded, and you choose player 5... boom.

Fix: apply the predicate *before* the count.

Comment: or just use Last on the predicate result

Comment: @Steve that isn't exactly what I'd call "random"... but I guess you can never be sure: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Yeah it needs to be completely random so I get a different result each time the code runs.